# Showing that $−i(U − E)(U + E)^{-1}$ is a Hermitian matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given $U \in \mathbb{C^{n \times n}}$ a unitary Matrix that doesn't have $-1$ as an Eigenvalue.

I am trying show that $U + I$ is invertiable and that $−i(U − E)(U + E)^{-1}$ is a Hermitian matrix.

Let $\lambda$ be an Eigenvalue of $U$
It follows that the Eigenvalues of $U + I$ have the form $\lambda+1$. Since $\lambda \neq -1$ then $U + I$ doesn't have zero as an Eigenvalue and therefore invertiable. (Is this correct?)

Let $B = −i(U − I)(U + I)^{-1} = (-iU + iI)(U + I)^{-1}$

We can show that $B^{H} = B$ or $B^{T} = \overline{B}$

$$\overline{B} = \overline{(-iU + iI)(U + I)^{-1}} = (-i \overline{U} - i I)(\overline{U} + I)^{-1}$$
$$B^{T} = (U^{T} + I)^{-1}(-i U^{T} + i I)$$

There is where I get stuck. Not sure how to relate $U^{T}$ and $\overline{U}$

Comment: $U$ is unitary. What does that tell you about $U^T$ and $\overline{U}$?

Comment: I am not really sure. Is $U^{T}  = U$ ?

Comment: It's $U^H=U^{-1}$.

Comment: What are the constraints on $E$ as a matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Since a unitary matrix is normal, it is unitarily diagonalizable. So all that needs to be shown is that if $|\lambda|=1$, $\lambda\ne-1$, then 
$$
-i\,\frac{\lambda-1}{\lambda+1}\in \mathbb R.
$$
For this, 
$$
-i\,\frac{\lambda-1}{\lambda+1}
=-i\,\frac{(\lambda-1)(\bar\lambda+1)}{|\lambda+1|^2},
$$
so we only care about the numerator now. And 
$$
-i(\lambda-1)(\bar\lambda+1)=-i(|\lambda|^2-1+\lambda-\bar\lambda)=-i(\lambda-\bar\lambda)=2\operatorname{Im}\lambda\in\mathbb R.
$$